# С# WinForms SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, winforms

Буду конкретным: при клике на toolstripComboBox, выбирая  строку из выпадающего списка, на dataGridView должна открываться таблица соответствующая названию выбранной строки. Таблицы из базы данных .mdf считываются нормально, фото 1 - это видно при открытии выпадающего списка, но на dataGridView ничего не появляется. Не понимаю в чём проблема.

Фото 1

[image: Фото 1]

Код:

```
  private void toolStripComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sTable = toolStripComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + sTable, connection);
            dat = new DataTable(sTable);
            bs = new BindingSource();

            connection.Open();

            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dat);
            bs.DataSource = dat;
            bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Если использовать редактор справа, то всё прекрасно работает, фото 2.
Код редактора на всякий случай тоже приложу.

Фото 2
[image: Фото 2]

Код:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(textBox1.Text, connection);
                dat = new DataTable();
                bs = new BindingSource();

                connection.Open();

                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dat);
                bs.DataSource = dat;
                bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Неправильно написан запрос. Попробуйте снова.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Код функции, загружающий названия таблиц в Items:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (connection)
        {
            connection.Open();
            DataTable tables = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
            foreach (DataRow row in tables.Rows)
            {
                string TableName = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                toolStripComboBox1.Items.Add(TableName);
            }
            connection.Close();
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Не хватает пробела после FROM.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло.

Comment: Действительно, значения sTable и SqlDataAdapter вообще не обновляются. Будто бы сам SelectedIndexChanged не работает, будто я ничего не выбираю из выпадающего списка. Добавил в пост код функции, загружающий названия таблиц в Items.

Comment: Начните с чистки кода. В вашем обработчике события `SelectedIndexChanged` есть неиспользуемый код: `DataSet`, `SqlCommandBuilder` - уберите их. У вас совершенно нелогично используются вперемешку поля и локальные переменные. Например, `BindingSource` в одном методе является полем, в другом - переменной. Вы зачем-то создаёте `connection`, но не используете его: в `SqlDataAdapter` передаётся `connectionString`.

Comment: Замечания поправил, в пост залил. Изменение DropDownStyle ничего не даёт.

Comment: РЕШЕНО ( немного кустарно ).
Посидел и подумал, так ли мне нужен ToolStripComboBox. Добавил на форму простой ComboBox, скопировал в него код из ToolStripComboBox, и, о чудо, всё заработало. Понятия не имею, почему ToolStrip не воспринимает событие SelectedIndexChanged. Кто-нибудь сможет объяснить?